# Why Tuple<int,int> takes the same amount of memory as Tuple<ushort,ushort>?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, memory, memory-management

When `ValueTuple<int,int>` or `ValueTuple<ushort,ushort>` are in Dictionary, they use the same amount of memory. Why type `Dictionary<long, ValueTuple<int,int>>` takes exactly the same amount of memory as `Dictionary<long, ValueTuple<ushort,ushort>>`??

I built a very simple console app to test this. The app was build under .NET7 and it's running on Windows10Pro x64:

```
var test = new Dictionary<long, (ushort foo, ushort bar)>();
for (long i = 0; i < 3000000; i++)
{
    test.Add(i, (100, 100));
}

Console.WriteLine($"Click to close");
Console.Read(); // <--- Get Snapshot while waiting for key 
Console.WriteLine($"Total keys: {test.Count}"); // <--- This is needed so that GC doesn't flush "test"
```

It turns out, that it doesn't matter if `foo` and `bar` variables are `int` or `ushort`. It uses exactly the same memory in both cases. I tested it with JetBrains dotMemory. Here are some screenshots:

1. When using `Dictionary<long, ValueTuple<int,int>>`:
   [image]
   [image]
2. When using `Dictionary<long, ValueTuple<ushort,ushort>>`:
   [image]
   [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that dictionary stores not just value tuples, but [`KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2?view=net-7.0) structs (and padding). The tuples itself will have different sizes:

```
unsafe
{
    Console.WriteLine(sizeof((int,int))); // 8
    Console.WriteLine(sizeof((ushort,ushort))); // 4
}
```

But due to them being wrapped in `KeyValuePair`'s and padding they will take all 16 bytes (for x64 process):

```cs
unsafe
{
    Console.WriteLine(sizeof(KeyValuePair<long, (ushort,ushort)>)); // 16
    Console.WriteLine(sizeof(KeyValuePair<long, (int,int)>)); //16
    // and just for fun
    Console.WriteLine(sizeof(KeyValuePair<int, (ushort,ushort)>)); // 8
}
```

For more info you can check [`StructLayoutAttribute.Pack`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.pack?view=net-7.0#remarks) remarks (`LayoutKind.Sequential` is default for structs):

> The `Pack` field controls the alignment of a type's fields in memory. It affects `LayoutKind.Sequential`. By default, the value is 0, indicating the default packing size for the current platform. The value of Pack must be 0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, or 128:

> The fields of a type instance are aligned by using the following rules:
>
> - The alignment of the type is the size of its largest element (1, 2, 4, 8, etc., bytes) or the specified packing size, whichever is smaller.
> - Each field must align with fields of its own size (1, 2, 4, 8, etc., bytes) or the alignment of the type, whichever is smaller. Because the default alignment of the type is the size of its largest element, which is greater than or equal to all other field lengths, this usually means that fields are aligned by their size. For example, even if the largest field in a type is a 64-bit (8-byte) integer or the Pack field is set to 8, Byte fields align on 1-byte boundaries, Int16 fields align on 2-byte boundaries, and Int32 fields align on 4-byte boundaries.
> - Padding is added between fields to satisfy the alignment requirements.

[Demo @sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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)

Comment: Can you specify exactly why 16? Why it takes less when `key` takes only 4 bytes (as int)?

Comment: If it was running under x86 system, then `KeyValuePair<long, (ushort,ushort)>`  would take less than `KeyValuePair<long, (int,int)>` correct?

Comment: @IshThomas added some quotes from the docs

Comment: @IshThomas _"If it was running under x86 system"_ - if I calculated correctly - then yes. Though it is late for me and I'm not ready to use coffee to mitigate that =) Also not necessarily even system, just x32 process possibly should do the trick.